# Setting up email for site hosted by IIS

Tags: iis, smtp, mail-server

I have just registered a domain, wirederp.dk, which runs on a IIS 7 (Windows 2008 R2).

In order to purchase a certificate, I need an email address for that domain (for instance: info@wirederp.dk). I dont need email for anything else but for receiving this single email.

IIS has some SMTP setup, but that seem to pertain to using an email from an ASP.NET solution.

Is it possible to set this up for IIS or does that require an Exchange server? Are there any alternatives to make such an email available? I am looking for an easy way out of this :)

I dont know if it makes a difference, but the domain runs an ASP.NET MCV 5 site.

Thanks in advance
Kind regards
S. Dalby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most domain registrars let you use an email forwarding service. If you setup a forwarding of info@wirederp.dk to your real email address you can get the domain ownership email from the ssl provider.

Comment: Hi thanks, but how do i setup a forward address in IIS?

Comment: Hi, I meant to setup a forwarding address with your domain provider, not IIS. I don't recommend setting up a mail server without proper research and time to invest, as it may become an open relay/backscatter source and become a problem for others.